# Finding which item(s) in a list is not present in the Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using the latest Java Realm local database backing a mobile app.

I have a Profile class and a Contact class in the app. Each Profile object can be associated with one or more Contact objects.

Upon startup, I want to reconcile against a similar Profile/Contact list on my website to insure that the mobile app is using the latest/greatest definition of the Profile/Contact relationship.

After validating the Profile during login, I then query the website to get the list of Contact email addresses associated with the Profile. I now need to do the following:

For each Contact email address in the list from the website, make sure that the local Realm Contact object shows as "connected" to the Profile object.

For each Contact object NOT in the list from the website, make sure that the local Realm Contact object shows as "not connected" to the Profile object.

So what I'm doing is after login, executing an AsyncTask that:

```
    try {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        RealmResults<Contact> contactResults;
        contactResults = realm.where(Contact.class).findAll();
        if ( contactResults.size() == 0 ) {
            // Nothing to do
            return false;
        }
        // First set everything as not connected, then set only those passed in as connected
        contactResults.setBoolean(IS_CONNECTED, false);
        // Now update just the email addresses passed in as connected
        contactResults = realm.where(Contact.class).in(EMAIL_ADDRESS, emailList.toArray(new String[0])).findAll();
        if ( contactResults.size() > 0) {
            contactResults.setBoolean(IS_CONNECTED, true);
        }
        //TODO - what if an item passed in is not yet in Contact list?
        success = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.d("Exception resetting contacts status: %s", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (success) {
            realm.commitTransaction();
        } else {
            realm.cancelTransaction();
        }
    }
```

How I've done the first two pieces of work seem ok to me - as this app won't be scaling to thousands of "friends", resetting the contact to FALSE for everyone then to TRUE for the current set retrieved from the website is doable.

However, the third piece has me stumped - is there a single call I can make to identify which, if any, of the email addresses in the passed array aren't actually in my Contact object RealmResults and therefore need to be added as new objects?

Seems inefficient to loop through that list and check each one, one at a time, particularly since I've already performed two queries.

The only solution I've come up with so far is this:

```
    try {
        realm.beginTransaction();
        fullContactResults = realm.where(Contact.class).findAll();
        if ( fullContactResults.size() > 0 ) {
            // First set everything as not connected, then set only those passed in as connected
            fullContactResults.setBoolean(IS_CONNECTED, false);
        }

        // Now for each item in the list we were passed in find it and update it, or add it.
        for ( String data : contactData ) {
            Contact c = null;
            String[] contactStruct = data.split(BODY_COMPONENTS_SEPARATOR);
            RealmResults<Contact> partialContactResults = realm.where(Contact.class)
                    .equalTo(EMAIL_ADDRESS,  contactStruct[CONNECTION_EMAIL_ELE])
                    .findAll();
            if (partialContactResults.size() > 0 ) {
                c = partialContactResults.first();
            } else {
                // Need to add the contact
                c = realm.createObject(Contact.class, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            }
            c.setConnected(true);
            c.setDisplayName(contactStruct[CONNECTION_FIRSTNAME_ELE] + " " + contactStruct[CONNECTION_LASTNAME_ELE]);
            c.setEmailAddress(contactStruct[CONNECTION_EMAIL_ELE]);
        }
        success = true;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.d("Exception resetting contacts status: %s", e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (success) {
            realm.commitTransaction();
        } else {
            realm.cancelTransaction();
        }
    }
```

Which does a loop and either updates or inserts.

Any better way?

Comment: How many fields are in the `Contact` model that need to keep any existing values? The reason I ask is with regards to the possibility of using `Realm.insertOrUpdate()` on all elements in `contactData` translated to `Contact` type. This might need a primary key which is available from the server also (to maintain a reference for existing objects). On the other hand, all this will do is similar to what you say you want to avoid - so maybe you may as well implement the filter of the array (based on a query for the object being present) yourself? That filter/convert would be easier in Kotlin...

Comment: Chris - there are roughly four fields that need to be updated to keep in sync with the website. But the primary key in my local Realm db (essentially a UUID) isn't the same as what is on the website (a primary email address).

Comment: Can you make the primary keys the same? If not then I think you just query whether each is in the realm individually, and add it if not.

Comment: Chris - let me make sure I understand your suggestion. Assuming I can utilize matching primary keys (and assuming the Contact structure is identical), then when I pull the list of contacts connected to the profile from the website, I can use an InsertOrUpdate call for the mobile app based on that list. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's pretty much it. The structure from the website doesn't *need* to be identical, but if it is then all is simpler. What format is the query result in? If JSON, then all is very simple by matching the two types, using a GSON builder (or similar) and then using `Realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson()`. Otherwise, use a 'conversion constructor' to make your local object from the query format.